# Block IP in Salesforce

Tags: api, login-errors, remote-access

I know that we have Trusted IP ranges/ Remote Site Setting for API calls. My scenario is something like, I have my users all over the world and they access salesforce.com via API. One of the user with a shared User Credential is accessing with wrong token and the User record is getting locked. I'm getting the IP from the related list under User but unable to find who it is. For a temporary solution, I thought I can block this IP. With that I observed that we have the feature in SFDC only to define set of allowed IP ranges but not block an IP or an IP range. I may be wrong :-) Any comments or suggestion please.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a range of legal login IP ranges on the profile. Any logins from outside those defined ranges will result in an error. This feature overrides network access when used.

Comment: My users will be roaming all over the world. So setting a specific IP ranges will not work. All I'm expecting is to block Suspicious IPs.

Comment: Here's an idea to support blacklisting IP address ranges: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfEyUAJ/block-ip-address-ranges But it has received surprisingly few votes so far.